# What is a uniform convergence counterpart to Bernstein's inequality?

Tags: probability-theory, inequality, random-variables

If Pollard's inequality is a uniform convergence counterpart to Hoeffding's inequality, what is a uniform convergence counterpart to Bernstein's inequality?

For completeness, I include all these three concentration inequalities here:

1. Hoeffding's inequality: If $\{X_i\}_{i=1}^n$ are i.i.d. random variables such that $a_i \leq X_i \leq b_i, \forall i$. Then, for any $\epsilon > 0$, we have
   $$
   P(\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^X X_i - \mathbb{E}[X_1] > \epsilon) \leq \exp( \frac{-2 n^2 \epsilon^2}{ \sum_{i=1}^n (a_i - b_i)^2 } ) 
   $$
2. Pollard's:
   [image]

where $\mathcal{N}$ is the covering number notation (From here https://jmlr.org/papers/v9/munos08a.html).

3. Bernstein's inequality:
   [image]

From here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernstein_inequalities_(probability_theory).

What I am looking for is a uniform convergence counterpart to the Bernstein's inequality, something possibly looks like this:

$$
P(\sup_{f \in \mathcal{F}} | \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n f(X_i) - \mathbb{E}[f(X_1)] | > \epsilon) \leq \text{covering_number} \cdot \exp( \frac{-0.5 \epsilon^2}{ \sum_{i=1}^n \mathbb{E}[X_i^2] + 1/3 M \epsilon } ).
$$

Answer (score 2):

This is exactly Theorem B in [http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~brecht/cs838docs/cuckersmale.pdf](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/%7Ebrecht/cs838docs/cuckersmale.pdf) :) :

[image]